# How to secure Single Page Application once user Logged in the system?

Tags: javascript, logging, browser, coldfusion, single-page-application

I have created login page for my Single page app. So far I have Ajax call that will check if user name exist and check their password. If user pass all security steps after AJAX call returns and it's successful I redirect them to Main page. This page should contain all elements of my SPA. Few things that I'm looking to prevent are go forward/back or click on reload button in the browser. So far if they login and system redirected them to Main page they can use these button and still will stay logged in. In my opinion this can cause some problems and might be security risk. Also I have some security steps on the top of my Main page where I'm using ColdFusion to check if user is logged in or not. Here is example that I have so far:

JQuery that handles login:

```
$('#ha_login').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var frmUN = $.trim($('#username').val()),
        frmPW = $('#password').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Authentication.cfc?method=checkLogin',
        data: {'username':frmUN,'password':frmPW},
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(obj){
        if(obj.STATUS == "200"){
            location.href = 'Application/MainPage.cfm';
        }else{
            location.reload(true);
        }
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Error: "+errorThrown);
    });
});
```

Authentication.cfc :

```
<cffunction name="checkLogin" access="remote" output="false" returnformat="JSON">
        <cfset fnResults = structNew()>

        <cfquery name="checkUser" datasource="#Application.dsn#">
            SELECT UserName, Password
            FROM Users
            WHERE UserName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#trim(FORM.username)#" maxlength="50">
                AND Active = 1
        </cfquery>

        <cfset storedPW = checkUser.Password>
        <cfset enteredPW = FORM.password>

        <cfif checkUser.recordCount NEQ '1' OR enteredPW NEQ storedPW> 
            <cfset fnResults.status = "400">
            <cfset fnResults.message = "<strong>Error!</strong> Invalid Username or Password!">
        <cfelse>
            <cfset SESSION.loggedin = true>
            <cfset fnResults.status = "200">
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn fnResults>
    </cffunction>
```

And here is my final Main.cfm page:

```
<cfif !structKeyExists(SESSION, "loggedin") OR SESSION.loggedin EQ false>
    <cflocation url="Login.cfm" addToken="false">
</cfif>
<h3>Welcome to My Application.</h3>
```

I'm wondering if there is anything else that I should include in my security steps on Main.cfm? Also is there a way to prevent/detect when user tries to leave Main.cfm? If they do I would logged out that user and redirect them to Login page. If anyone can help with this or have some useful examples please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tell me that you are passing the username and password over a TLS secured connection. Also that you are not just storing the password as entered into your database.  It must be hashed with strong encryption. [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: @Miguel-F I have TLS and I do has my password before storing in DB. I just didn't include those information in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try the onbeforeunload event: It is fired just before the page is unloaded. It also allows you to ask back if the user really wants to leave. See the demo [onbeforeunload Demo](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028110528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm).

Alternatively, you can send out an Ajax request when he leaves.

Comment: Is there a way to redirect them to Login page after they click Leave the page? I have tried location.href but that still keeps the user on the existing page.